# In C# string how to replace two chararacters ignoring a number

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am editing a serialized string becuase when deserilized it gives a parse error.
so from a long Serialized string I want to edit `"myVar\": \"0.2 mm"` with `"myVar\": \"0.2"`
if I use the follwoing code it works

```
string NewString = Serializedstring.Replace($"myVar\": \"0.2 mm", $"myVar\": \"0.2")
```

but my `0.2` is a varible that may change with every occurance. so all I want is to remove `mm` from the string `"myVar\": \"0.2 mm"`

Comment: It would probably be better to write a `JsonConverter` to remove the units during serialization, rather than to try and manipulate the serialized data.

Comment: @Llama when serialized it added mm to the value 0.2 that means it was a double but now a has become a string

Comment: Show your model and serialization code then. None of the JSON serializers for .NET will automatically add "mm".

Comment: So is the problem with your serialisation code rather than your hack here to fix it?

Comment: @Llama and DavidG yes the issue you identified is correct. and its fixed. but some users of the application have saved the data before the fix. when they try to use application during deserialzation they find this error. the hack is the only solution

Comment: "The hack is the only solution." - I disagree. A `JsonConverter` would likely be a much better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JSON is coming in with two different formats, rather than trying to hack the JSON string into something usable, it is much safer to use a custom `JsonConverter`. For example:

```
public class MillimetreJsonConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // First try to get a double, if it works then simply return it
        if(reader.TryGetDouble(out var val))
        {
            return val;
        }
        
        // Otherwise we get the string value e.g. "0.2 mm" and
        // do some simple string manipulation on it
        var value = reader.GetString()!;
        value = value.Replace(" mm", "");
        
        if(double.TryParse(value, out var result))
        {
            return result;
        }

        // If we get here, perhaps we should throw an exception?
        return 0;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, double value, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // You can fill this in if you need it
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can modify the class to deserialise into, assuming your JSON looks like this `{"myVar": "0.2 mm"}`,:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MillimetreJsonConverter))]
    public double myVar { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, it's simple to deserialise:

```
var foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend 2 alternate approaches

1)match what you can.
var str = NewString.Replace(" mm,\"", "");
if your string is not going to have a space followed by mm" anywhere else that should be fine.

2)A safer option would be to deserialize it into something that can handle it (i assume your deserializing that property to a number currently) and then string replace the property and map it to what you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this, RegEx, String tokenisation, char array searching

RegEx is probably the closest to what you are currently doing
the Regular expression syntax is described here [Basics of RegEx](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)

the pattern `[0-9.]+` should match an decimal number but be warned it will also match anything that inclues numbers and dots such as ip addresses
so if you have a regex of

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"([0-9.]+) mm")
<your string> = rx.Replace(<Your string>, @"$1");
```

the details are :

- `[0-9.]` any number or dot
- `+` one or more of what ever preceded it
- `()` a group that is of special interest
- `$1` the number of the group that you want to replace the match with
  note `$0` is the entire input string

this will replace any string that is (number) mm with just the value of the number